# jquery ui drag, grabbing inner img and not outer contianer

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Hopefully someone has had this problem before.

I have this html:

```
<div class='item_to_drag'><img src="" /></div>
```

I use this jquery ui command:

```
$('.item_to_drag').draggable();
```

Problem is that majority of the time, the IMG ends up being was is draggable and not the container. has anyone experience this problem?

Comment: Declare your image as draggable if you won't have the outer container. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry. I might not have explained it properly. I want the outer div to be draggable, not the image.

Comment: Your code above makes the outer div draggable. Please, complete your question